# Retorno de valores de uma coluna da tabela X que tem 1 código em comum

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, array

estou precisando resolver um problemão.
Tenho uma tabela de respostas de uma enquete onde as respostas feitas com checkboxes ficam em linhas diferentes com um codigo em comum, o da questão respondida, exemplo: cod_questao = 100 / cod_resposta = 200
                     cod_questao = 100 / cod_resposta = 201. como são duas linhas não consigo no foreach() fazer com que venham em uma única linha no html. Vocês tem algum exemplo para que eu possa tentar resolver esse problema?

Comment: Não ficou claro o seu problema. Tem como se expressar melhor?

Comment: obrigado pela disponibilidade em vir resolver meu problema com o código, acabei resolvendo com meu superior aqui do estágio. Tivemos que modificar a query em um método da DAO que tinha sido criada pra não repetir na tela duas vezes o mesmo campo cod_questao por exemplo e só repetir a resposta. mais uma vez obrigado

Comment: Posta a solução para que outros usuários possam ver

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem, os registro no banco são mais ou menos assim:

cod_questao       cod_resposta

> ```
>   1            200
>   1            300
>   2            100
>   2            200
> ```

Então você terá de fazer o foreach controlando a quebra de linha, mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
$questao ='';
foreach($array_de_respostas as $resposta){
    if($questao != $respostas['id_questao']){
       if ($questao != ''){
          //procedimento para fechar a linha anterior, se o $questao for vazio é a primeira vez então não precisa fechar
       }
       $questao = $respostas['id_questao']; 
       //procedimento para abrir a linha
    }
    //procedimento da formação da linha 
}
```